# "Re-share" wifi in Linux

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, router

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can a Linux machine act as both a wireless client and access point simultaneously using a single physical WLAN interface?](https://superuser.com/questions/155795/can-a-linux-machine-act-as-both-a-wireless-client-and-access-point-simultaneously)

Quick scenario:

- Have 2 devices with wifi cards
- Only 1 computer can connect to the area wifi network due to security issues.

Is there anyway to make the connected computer simultaneously act as a wifi router and have the other device to connect to the internet through it? Or is it impossible to do that without two cards?

Comment: If they are preventing this for security reasons do you really thin you should be trying change this?  Intentionally bypassing security could end in you being fired, jailed, or otherwise punished.

Answer (score 1):

You will need two cards. Or perhaps you can use your wired NIC to connect to the second computer.

Answer (score 0):

[This article](http://www.linuxplanet.com/linuxplanet/reports/7087/1/) suggests 5 products, but I haven't tried any of them.

Answer (score 0):

If your computers have wired network cards also and you got a network cable

Windows can do internet connection sharing of one network connection over another, go to the properties of your connected wifi connection then you can share it and select your local area connection to share with, then plugin your other computer via LAN cable