# Can we create a VAP in sta mode and another VAP in ap mode in MadWiFi

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-access-point

I have am working with a Atheros chip and madwifi and I am trying to set up VAPs one in sta and one in ap. I am able to set up multiple VAPs in ap mode but when I set up the first VAP in sta and then try setting up another VAP in ap I get wlanconfig: ioctl: Input/output error. Is it possible to create one VAP in sta and another in ap using MadWiFi.

Comment: I think, you can create virtual interface for sta and ap. try it