# My Own WiFi Router + DHCP Server on a Public Wifi

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-router, bridge, dhcp-server, bridge-router

I live in the dorms of my University, that has a public WiFi for each building.

I have several computers in my apt (+ a RPI, a Chromecast Audio, and a WiFi printer) which I want to connect to my own secure network that would have access to the internet through the public WiFi.

I don't have any ethernet ports in my apt, or anywhere around it - just WiFi access based on routers scattered throughout the building.

I am currently using my Raspberry Pi as a wifi bridge, but it works quite poorly.

I'm looking for some hardware that could do the job. I know that any windows pc can do the job (using connectify, or some new feature in windows 10 that allows it), but I want a dedicated low-energy router to do it, preferably one that could create a 5GHz network.

I looked all around the internet, but aside from Traveler Routers, which hold many functions that I don't need like batteries, power-banks or a small size, and are therefore pretty expensive, I did not find ANYTHING that I could clearly interpret as something that could do what I need it to.

What kind of hardware can I get to get this done? What features should I be looking for?

Comment: cantenna?

...654321

Comment: I don't need to extend my wifi reception, I want to create my own network with a SSID and password, that will give away local IPs and will access the internet using the public WiFi I have in the apartment.

Comment: You are asking an off-topic question (hardware shopping). Please read [On-Topic](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic), [How do I ask a good question?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://superuser.com/help/dont-ask). Try [Hardware Recommendations](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/).  but please first read [What is required for a question to be 'high quality'?"](http://meta.hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/205/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-be-high-quality).

Comment: I do this in hotels all the time with an Asus RT-N66 router, picked it up for $50 refurbished and installed DD-WRT. 2.4Ghz is client to hotel/public WiFi and ethernet ports and 5Ghz WiFi are for my stuff. It is exactly what your trying to do, works very well. Any DD-WRT compatible dual band router should be able to accomplish the same thing.

Comment: An interesting question, but as written it already has attracted multiple close votes since it reads as a product recommendation, which is off-topic here on [Su].  **How** do I do this rather than with **which product does this** is an interesting question though.

Comment: @acejavelin
I finally got a dual-band router running DD-WRT, and some time to work on it.
It would be very nice and helpful of you if you could share with me how you managed to make the configuration work :)
I have some but limited knowledge on networking, I read a lot online and even consulted a friend who is "in the business", but I failed to make it work...

Comment: https://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Client_Mode_Wireless

Comment: I actually used this tutorial, but it only works for about 5 minutes or so after I reset my router, and then disconnects from the internet. It's actually an improvement over my last attempt a couple of months ago, when it gave me a super slow connection or didn't work at all

Answer (score 3):

**Ugly hack**

With Linux a WiFi card can be client and AP simultaneously, see [Can a Linux machine act as both a wireless client and access point simultaneously using a single physical WLAN interface?](https://superuser.com/questions/155795)

It looks like the Raspberry Pi can't do it but some routers compatible with OpenWRT can, see https://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/recipes/ap_sta and http://lechacal.com/wiki/index.php/Repeat_a_Wifi_Hotspot

Performance will suffer as there will be only one WiFi module sharing one frequency for everything, or using 2 frequencies and spending half the time in each.

Some routers allow for a separate guest network (which is 2 access points so not the same, but still 2 simultaneous profiles for 1 WiFi module) so stability should be OK - in some cases at least, it depends on the drivers.

**Hackish**

Use 2 routers one client and one AP, connected with an Ethernet cable and with routing setup between them. It's still low power and having two devices doesn't really matter here as it's a fixed installation. WiFi performance will be normal as there will be two physical WiFi modules.

One router needs to be able to act as a WiFi client, the other needs to be able to use Ethernet for WAN. You can use 2 Raspberry Pi or 2 WiFi routers.

**Clean**

Buy something like a RB433 from Mikrotik and 2 WiFi modules, it's built for the job.

Comment: Well, actually the Pi _does_ work, but it gives me bad latency and occasional crashes.
I will look and see if I can find a router that supports OpenWRT.
I am looking for a low power consumption solution, so a regular pc on linux will probably not do...
Thanks!